# Using STM32 I/O pins as power supply

Tags: current, stm32, gpio, maximum-ratings

I'm designing a device where I have multiple sensors controlled by an STM32 microcontroller (STM32F030F4P6). It's a low power device that is supposed to work for months or years on single use batteries, so I thought I could switch each sensor on, read its value and then switch it off until I need to check it again.

Each of these sensors draw anywhere between 0.1uA ~ 5mA in various working conditions which is within the limits of I/O sink/source current. My concern is that each of them have a few hundred nano-farad capacitors on their supply pins which means at the moment of power up, they will probably draw more than the allowable current from the I/O pins. It this going to damage the MCU or can I use GPIO to power external devices?

Some of these sensors have an enable pin and draw very little current when disabled,  but some of the more power consuming ones don't have an enable pin. I might have to use them at different times so I can't just control all of them using an external MOSFET or some other kind of switch.

Comment: It'll be fine.. The pin can't deliver more current than it's sourcing transistor, so the voltage will just ramp slower. Thermal damage is unrealistic if you don't switch the lines on/off constantly every other millisecond.

Answer (score 2):

You can limit the inrush current to capacitors via a series resistor to allowable maximum value in data sheet, but it will also limit the voltage to sensor when it draws DC current.

Use a FET for each sensor instead of one FET. Or use a load switch that integrates it all for you.